# Detecting Enter/Return on Keydown event in C++

Tags: c++, mfc, keypress

I am trying to detect in my application, if the <kbd>Enter</kbd>/<kbd>Return</kbd> buttons are pressed. My problem is that the **LVN_KEYDOWN** event (Indicates that a key has been pressed) does not detect the  <kbd>Enter</kbd>/<kbd>Return</kbd> key.

I have seen similar questions for other languages, but can not find a solution for C++.

My event to read the key press is:

```
void ListOption::OnLvnKeydownList1(NMHDR *pNMHDR, LRESULT *pResult)
{
    LPNMLVKEYDOWN pLVKeyDow = reinterpret_cast<LPNMLVKEYDOWN>(pNMHDR);
    // TODO: Add your control notification handler code here
    if(pLVKeyDow->wVKey == VK_RETURN)
    {
        OnItemActivateList1(pNMHDR, pResult);
        *pResult = 1;
    }
    *pResult = 0;
}
```

This code works for almost any key, execept for the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key.

My dialog has only one button, and it's "Default Button" value is FALSE.  How is it possible to detect the keypress?

**Update:** My application uses modal dialogs..  It contains a CImageSheet that contains CImagePages(tabs).  Here is an image to explain better (*I have placed grey blocks to hide some private data*).
[image]

When I press <kbd>Enter</kbd>, I wish to open a new dialog to change the option.  Currently this is done with the **LVN_ITEMCTIVATE** event (when the user double clicks an item):

Comment: you need to provide more context about this, because I've tested this on a CListView it does work. please add the class declaration, message map etc... maybe, try to reproduce your problem in a simple application creating a new project with minimal fetures

Comment: You may need to respond to [`WM_GETDLGCODE`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms645425%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) messages and return the appropriate flags.

Comment: @Robson I have updated the question to explain a bit better.  Please note I am using MFC's List Control, not CListView.

Comment: @TheForestAndTheTrees Thank you, but this is a different question. also, the question you linked to has been closed for being [too broad].

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can override `PreTranslateMessage` in the window which owns the ListView. In this case it seems to be a `CPropertyPage`.

```
BOOL CMyPropertyPage::PreTranslateMessage(MSG* pMsg)
{
    //optional: you can handle keys only when ListView has focus
    if (GetFocus() == &List) 
    if (pMsg->message == WM_KEYDOWN)
    {
      if (pMsg->wParam == VK_RETURN)
      {
         //return 1 to eat the message, or allow for default processing
         int sel = List.GetNextItem(-1, LVNI_SELECTED);
         if (sel >= 0)
         {
            MessageBox("VK_RETURN");
            TRACE("ListView_GetNextItem %d\n", sel);
            return 1;
         }
         else
            TRACE("ListView_GetNextItem not-selected, %d\n", sel);
      }

      if (pMsg->wParam == VK_ESCAPE)
      {
         //do nothing!
      }
    }

    return CPropertyPage::PreTranslateMessage(pMsg);
}
```

Comment: I've done some testing, and this looks like the only way to do it.

Comment: Thank you.  This event does detect the 'Return' key.  However, I still do not know how to call my `OnItemActivateList1(pNMHDR, pResult) ` method.  Is there any way to do so within this event?

Comment: `LVN_ITEMACTIVATE` works fine if ListView's parent is non-dialog. But if it's dialog, then Return and Esc keys are used by dialog for default button and Cancel button. Technically you can leave this alone because this is the standard behavior. Or you can override it. I made some changes to find GetNextItem so you can process it or continue.