# How to use CDialog::SetDefId with a non button control?

Tags: c++, mfc, dialog

I've come across CDialog::SetDefId and while it is pretty easy and clear that it is for "pushbuttons" I wanted to use this functionality with a non button control.I understand that you have to press <kbd>Enter</kbd> or <kbd>Return</kbd> to make the dialog use that ID

If I set nID to 0 in the CDialog::OnInitDialog and have no default button setted the dialog will default to CDialog::OnOk, If I do have a default button setted, the dialog will push that button as expected.

The thing is that I want to make this work for a non button control, so if I set nID to a control that is not a pushbutton, the dialog will do nothing even If I set the message handler for the keydown event or NM_RETURN, it doesn't matter if the control has focus or not, the dialog will still do nothing if I press <kbd>Enter</kbd> or <kbd>Return</kbd>.

How can I make the control be the default control without using stuff like PreTranslateMessage? and which message is sent to the control?

thanks in advance

Comment: There is no such thing as a "default" for non button controls. For example what should a "default" radio button or a "default" edit control do ? What are you trying to achieve ? This looks like an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) to me.

Comment: I was looking at this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30127282/detecting-enter-return-on-keydown-event-in-c?noredirect=1#comment48370597_30127282 and was wondering if there could be a default non button control, so any input would be passed to it as default. It is not a problem that I need to solve but rather I'm using it to study about mfc

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it only works with buttons but you can use `SetFocus` to change focus to any other control:

```
BOOL CMyDlg::OnInitDialog()
{
    CDialog::OnInitDialog();
    GetDlgItem(IDC_CHECK1)->SetFocus();
    return 0;  // return TRUE  unless you set the focus to a control
}
```

In this example the OK button may still be the default button. `Enter` key will go to default button, probably `IDOK`. But space key it will change the check box `IDC_CHECK1`.

There has to be a default button. If you don't want one, then add a fake button, lets say `IDC_BUTTON1`, and make it the default button and not visible, then you don't see a default button (you can still add `IDC_BUTTON1` to message map and decide what to do with Enter key)

Comment: thank you very much fro your answer. using the setFocus and pressing enter the dialog will still close, using the "other button" will not make the control I want the default control, maybe this is just not possible with current MFC

Comment: @Robson: Neither current nor future versions of MFC will enable, what you are looking for. This limitation is built into the dialog manager. That is a good thing, too, as it prevents people like yourself from abusing certain features. You should handle [WM_GETDLGCODE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms645425.aspx) instead. See [How To Use the WM_GETDLGCODE Message](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/83302) for additional information.